# 2 gauss peak fitting python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit my data by two Gauss peaks, but it's obviously wrong. I don't know where it's wrong. Here's a look at the script. I refer to many different writing methods, but none of them can fit. I guess I'm missing something and not noticing. Also, I try to consider mean theory.But nothing change.I can use labview to fit, but it can't be done with python. I hope to find out the error.I wonder if there is a problem with the fitting PTV or "popt". Also, I found out that my "pcov" value is infinite, which seems weird.

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('C:/Users/user/Desktop/sheet1 test.txt', delimiter=',')
print(data.shape)
print(data.dtype)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = data[:, 0]  
y = data[:, 1]  

#fitting function
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
#individual peak
def gauss(x,a,w,p,c):
    #C = 0
    fun_val = 0 + ((a/1.253*w)*np.exp(-2*((x-p)**2/w**2)))
    return fun_val

#double peak
def d_gauss(x, a1, p1,a2, p2):    
    #w1 = 0.049
    #w2 = 0.029
    #c1 = c2 = 0
    fun_val1 = 0 + ((a1/1.253*0.049)*np.exp(-2*((x-p1)**2/0.049**2)))
    fun_val2 = 0 + ((a2/1.253*0.029)*np.exp(-2*((x-p2)**2/0.029**2)))
    
    return fun_val1 + fun_val2 
initial_gauss_peak = [1.43896,186.097,  1.4743,393.263]
#bnd = ( (lower limit )  , ( upper limit ) )
bnd = ((1.4,10 ,1.45,100) , (1.5 ,1000 ,1.52,5000) ) 

#fitting
popt,pcov = curve_fit(d_gauss,x,y, p0 = initial_gauss_peak, bounds = bnd)

yfit = gauss(x, popt[0], popt[1] ,popt[2], popt[3])
yfit1 = gauss(x, popt[0], 0.049 ,popt[1], 0)
yfit2 = gauss(x, popt[2], 0.029 ,popt[3], 0)

plt.plot(x,y ,'o', label = 'data')
plt.plot(x,yfit1 , label = 'peak 1' , color = 'b')
plt.plot(x,yfit2 , label = 'peak 2' , color = 'c')
plt.plot(x ,yfit ,linewidth = 2, label = 'fit' , color = 'k')
plt.legend()

#plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('X Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
plt.title('Scatter Plot')
plt.show()
```

[image: fit graph]

Comment: That looks like only one peak?

Comment: You swapped `a` and `p` in your initial guesses!

Comment: Width is fixed? Why?

Comment: @Reinderien This needs to take two I tried to take a peak fit but it didn't work

Comment: @mikuszefski  What do you mean I swapped with ```a``` and ``` p``` ? Because I didn't write the swap command in the program. The fixed width is because I have to fit 3000 pictures later, and this width is the most suitable for me. Their relationship changes with time, so some values must be fixed.

Comment: Possibby there is a problem with the data. I cannot check because the data isn't given in the question. Would you mind joint to your question the data on two numerical files (x and y distinctly, not graphical ).

Comment: ... I mean that `d_gauss() takes `(a1, p1, a2, p2)` but your initial values are in the order `(p1, a1, p2, a2)`! So initial values are far off and the fit converges to whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The curve appears not symetrical. It seems that they are two peaks :

[image]

Don't take for granted the above numerical result because the data comes from graphical scanning of the OP picture which is not accurate.